# In Sublime Text 2, how do I make a key mapping to move the cursor up or down multiple lines?

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'm trying the following key mapping, but it only moves the cursor up one line at a time. I'd like it to move 10 lines at a time. It seems the "amount" paramater is ignored.

```
{ "keys": ["alt+down"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true, "amount": 10.0} },
{ "keys": ["alt+up"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": false, "amount": 10.0} }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a plugin that gets called from a key binding, this plugin can then collect the current line and move it down or up.

This [post on the offical sublime forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5513) has an example how to move back and forth 10 lines with a plugin.

Comment: Seems ridiculous that you'd need to create a plugin for this...

Comment: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/ I think you can submit idea's and features here jondavidjohn. I think the flexible plugin system is one of sublime's biggest strengths.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a plugin in order to achieve this: https://github.com/sflip/SublimeMoveMore

Answer (score 1):

I've also had success using the [multiple commands command](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8677) to achieve command concatenation in bindings.

You won't need a separate plugin for this, though you will need to repeat the same command a bit. Here's an example from my bind file.

```
{
    "keys": ["H"],
    "command": "run_multiple_commands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            {"command": "set_motion", "args": {
            "motion": "vi_move_by_characters_in_line",
            "motion_args": {"forward": false, "extend": true }}},
            {"command": "set_motion", "args": {
            "motion": "vi_move_by_characters_in_line",
            "motion_args": {"forward": false, "extend": true }}},
            {"command": "set_motion", "args": {
            "motion": "vi_move_by_characters_in_line",
            "motion_args": {"forward": false, "extend": true }}},
            {"command": "set_motion", "args": {
            "motion": "vi_move_by_characters_in_line",
            "motion_args": {"forward": false, "extend": true }}},
            {"command": "set_motion", "args": {
            "motion": "vi_move_by_characters_in_line",
            "motion_args": {"forward": false, "extend": true }}},
            {"command": "set_motion", "args": {
            "motion": "vi_move_by_characters_in_line",
            "motion_args": {"forward": false, "extend": true }}},
            {"command": "set_motion", "args": {
            "motion": "vi_move_by_characters_in_line",
            "motion_args": {"forward": false, "extend": true }}},
            {"command": "set_motion", "args": {
            "motion": "vi_move_by_characters_in_line",
            "motion_args": {"forward": false, "extend": true }}},
            {"command": "set_motion", "args": {
            "motion": "vi_move_by_characters_in_line",
            "motion_args": {"forward": false, "extend": true }}},
            {"command": "set_motion", "args": {
            "motion": "vi_move_by_characters_in_line",
            "motion_args": {"forward": false, "extend": true }}},
        ]
    },
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
},
```

Looks awful, I know, but this is apparently the standard way to get your cursor moved back 10 lines.

If there was some way to find out what the command invocation is for whatever typing "10h" would do in vintage mode, that should be more elegant.