# How to remap motions with a count in Sublime Text 2 vintage mode?

Tags: sublime-text-2

In my .vimrc, I have space remapped to move down 10 lines, and backspace remapped to move up 10 lines respectively:

```
nnoremap <space> 10jzz
nnoremap <backspace> 10kzz
```

I want to configure this behavior in Sublime Text 2. So far I've figured out how to remap space and backspace to move up and down one line at a time in Key Bindings - User:

```
{
    "keys": [" "],
    "command": "set_motion",
    "args": {
        "motion": "move",
        "motion_args": {
            "by": "lines",
            "forward": true,
            "extend": true
        },
        "linewise": true
    },
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
},
{
    "keys": ["backspace"],
    "command": "set_motion",
    "args": {
        "motion": "move",
        "motion_args": {
            "by": "lines",
            "forward": false,
            "extend": true
        },
        "linewise": true
    },
    "context": [{"key": "setting.command_mode"}]
}
```

I can't figure out how to repeat the command. Is there an option that will make the motion repeat, or a better way to do this?

Comment: There's apparently another thread that covers this topic:

http://superuser.com/questions/490095/in-sublime-text-2-how-do-i-make-a-key-mapping-to-move-the-cursor-up-or-down-mul

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple plugin to move up and down more than one line at a time. [Check it out](https://github.com/sflip/SublimeMoveMore)!